# Any way to get the when-visible height of an invisible element?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a flyout menu, in which some flyouts are hiding themselves and others are unhiding themselves, based on where the mouse is. Typical flyouts you see on shopping sites, e.g. Amazon.

I'm trying to insert from JavaScript in the background to set padding for text shown on these flyouts dynamically, using jQuery.

Problem is that I need to get the heights of certain elements, and when I use `.height()` value for a given element using jQuery, it returns zero, if the flyout section its a part of is hidden (`display:none`). If I unhide the flyout section, the height of that element changes to whatever its height should be when the parent flyout is visible.

So is there any way to read the actual height of an element when it will be visible, when its actually invisible ?

Comment: You can make parent visible set the position:absolute and set top:-9999 and left:-9999, this way you will be able to measure the height of the element using jqeury .height() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "invisible" you mean having `display: none`, then no there is not.

However, you can make an element practically invisible at the same time it is technically visible, e.g. with `position: absolute; left: -99999px`. This will allow you to measure it.

Of course there are certain restrictions even with this technique (depending on other styles, the element might be laid out differently when absolutely positioned; if it is not absolutely positioned then it will take up space in the layout, affecting other elements) but there's quite a bit you *can* do with it.

Answer (score 0):

We'd have to see your actual HTML and code to know what the best solution for you is.  My guess is that you can probably use relative positioning to solve your problem without having to know the height.

But to answer your specific question, one way to get an element to layout to its actual height without showing it on screen is to temporarily change it to:

```
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
display: block;
```

This will make it technically visible in the browser (so it will get layout) even though it won't be something the end-user can see.  Then, read it's height, then put it's position and visibility and display values back to what they were.

---

In fact, there are some circumstances where jQuery's `.height()` method already does this temporary swap for you (I just stepped through a test case and saw it do it) so I think to help you further and more directly, we'd really need to see your actual HTML and javascript to see what your specific issue is.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to throw the element offscreen, unhide it, get the height, and then hide it again.

```
<script>
function getMenuItemHeight(elementSelector) {
  var elementHeight = 0;
  var myElement = $(elementSelector);
  myElement.css({'position':'absolute','left':'-9999x'}).show();
  elementHeight = myElement.height();
  myElement.hide().css({'position':'','left':''});
  return elementHeight;
}
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could clone the element and place it in an off-screen container, get the height, then  destroy the copy. The only issue with this is that it may not have the CSS styling of your menu which means you might not get the same height value. But that's easy to fix if you simply add a CSS rule for items in your off-screen container.

```
<script>
function getMenuItemHeight(elementSelector) {
  var elementHeight = 0;
  var myElement = $(elementSelector).clone();
  var container = $('<div id="offscreen-container" style="position:absolute;left:-9999px">');
  container.append(myElement);
  elementHeight = myElement.height();
  container.remove();
  return elementHeight;
}
</script>
```